# How to use flexbox to make my Image gallery

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to know how to make my image gallery on the landscapes fill the white spaces with other images next to the portrait photo of the wind turbine.

The website where I’ve applied my css code is at [photography.comsma.com](https://photography.comsma.com/)

This is my `css`

```
    .gallery{
        padding: 50px;
    }
    .ImageTile{

        padding: 10px;
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .ImageTile img {

        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width:1100px) {
        .gallery{
            padding:5%;
        }
        .ImageTile{
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
        }

    }
```

And this is my `html`

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="ImageTile">
        <img src="/assets/Photography/Landscapes/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="ImageTile">
        <img src="/assets/Photography/Landscapes/2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="ImageTile">
        <img src="/assets/Photography/Landscapes/3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="ImageTile">
        <img src="/assets/Photography/Landscapes/4.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="ImageTile">
        <img src="/assets/Photography/Landscapes/5.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="ImageTile">
        <img src="/assets/Photography/Landscapes/6.jpg">
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Add some demo images as well.

Comment: the images are on my website, its at photography.comsma.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case I would make 3 modifications:

First, I would add this rule to the ImageTile:

```
.ImageTile{
          width: 100%;
 }
```

Then, I would define a subclass for the tall picture in the html tag:

```
    <div class="ImageTile tall">
      <img src="https://photography.comsma.com/assets/Photography/Landscapes/2.jpg">
    </div>
```

Finally, I would make the @media query aiming for bigger screens. One rule making the gallery a grid, and one for the tall picture to position itself on the 2nd column and using 3 normal images spaces for the height:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:1100px) {
    .gallery{
        display:grid;
        grid-template: "ImageTile ImageTile";
    }
   .ImageTile.tall {
      grid-row: 1/span 3;
      grid-column: 2;
  }
    

}
```

I would lose the @media query for small screens, or maybe just leave the padding rule.

Here's my codepen so you can see it in action:

[Codepen for COMSMA PHOTOGRAPHY](https://codepen.io/francovici/pen/oNbQyNd)

Comment: awesome i love it, i never thought to set a default for minimum screens.

Answer (score 0):

```
.gallery{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   }
```

Comment: can i get link to your code so I can see your work and add more suggestions

Comment: this is my github repo https://github.com/comsma/COMSMA-Photography/tree/master/src/app but i guess i want to kinda make a gallery like this square space gallery pictured here -> http://www.amandanilsson.se/

Comment: Okay maybe I’m wrong about it being a square space website

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.